# IPython: Render HTML text in Colab if a condition is met

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ipython

I want to be able to render some HTML text in Colab **if a condition is met** but it does not work. I have imported `HTML` from `IPython.display` and this works...

```
HTML('<h1>Hello, World</h1>')
```

But what I really want is this...

```
if True:
  HTML('<h1>Hello, World</h1>')
```

I have also tried...

```
if True:
  IPython.display.display_html('<h1>Hello, World</h1>')
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `display()` to display your page, e.g.  `display(HTML('<h1>Hello, World</h1>'))`